# Python JustPy QTable custom row color

Tags: python, quasar, justpy

I am creating QTable:

```
some_table = jp.QTable(
    hide_bottom=True,
    title=f'Some Table Title',
    data=[],
    columns=some_table_columns,
    a=some_table_div,
    dense=True,
    style="margin-bottom:25px"
)
```

next, I have

```
for some_item in some_item_str_list:
    new_row = {"name": some_item}
    some_table.data.append(new_row)
```

how can I make some rows to have different style, eg. being bold or red, depending on some condition, eg.

```
for some_item in some_item_str_list:
    # if some_item == "value1":
    #     make it red
    
    new_row = {"name": some_item}
    some_table.data.append(new_row)
```